# Magento2 : How to send a request for a page and get the page status?

Tags: magento2, php, 404-page, php-7.2, curl

I want to check if the status of the page is not `200`, then add it to the array along with the status and send it to the mail at the end of the script

I can't finish the code, tell me how to implement it. My code stops working on the line `$this->curl->get($url);`

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Test\Cron;

class Test
{
    protected $curl;

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->curl = $curl;
    }

    public function execute(): void
    {
        $urls = [
            'http://example.com/one',
            'http://example.com/two',
            'http://example.com/three'
        ];

        $problemUrls = [];

        $this->curl->setCredentials('basicLogin', 'basicPass');

        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            try {
                $this->curl->get($url);
                $response = $this->curl->getHeaders();
                if ($response === 404) {
                    array_push($problemUrls, $url);
                }

                if (!empty($problemUrls)) {
                    mail('test@gmail.com', 'test@gmail.com', var_export($problemUrls, true));
                }
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical('Error Curl', ['exception' => $e]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which are your errors?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the line: $this->curl->get($url); but the next line should probably be: $response = $this->curl->getStatus();